# No PHP 7, o método de classe pode conter um nome de palavra-chave? Isso é bom ou ruim?

Tags: php, sintaxe, php-7

O PHP 7, lançou uma série de inovações para a linguagem PHP. Inclusive, eu reparei  que agora as classes pode ter métodos com nome de palavras-chaves. O estranho é que as classes não podem ter, mas os método podem (vixe!)

Por exemplo, isso é válido no PHP7:

```
class X{
 public function foreach(array $array, \Closure $closure) : boolean {
 }
}
```

A minha curiosidade é: Isso é bom ou ruim?

É realmente uma vantagem poder declarar o nome de métodos como sendo de uma palavra-chave?

Qual foi o motivo que levou o PHP-7 a incluir essa nova funcionalidade na linguagem, se antes isso gerava um `Parse Error`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Globally reserved words as property, constant, and method names within classes, interfaces, and traits are now allowed. This reduces the surface of BC breaks when new keywords are introduced and avoids naming restrictions on APIs*.
>
> *This is particularly useful when creating internal DSLs with fluent interfaces*.

Existe uma razão para isso. Segundo o manual isso reduz a quebra de compatibilidade caso uma palavra chave nova seja adicionada e tenha sido usado como uma 'função' como por exemplo o `yield` no Laravel ([exemplo do problema SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32564772/1342547)). A outra vantagem é manter o vocabulário na criação de uma DSL (*domanin specific language*) ou seja não é preciso procurar um sinônimo.

Exemplo:

```
Project::new('Project Name')->private()->for('purpose here')->with('username here');
```

Comment: Ia ficar muito estranho a declaração `private function private() : boolean {}`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters e a `public function function()`? :D

Comment: Muito bom ter citado esse problema do `Laravel`, mas esse problema ocorreu no Laravel 3, e não no 4. No 4 o problema já estava solucionado

Comment: @WallaceMaxters então no link que está a pergunta ele fala do 4, mas posso editar sem problemas.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters deixa p amanha depois do almoço p dar tempo p alguem responder :)