# Nomes de operadores do PHP no controller

Tags: php

Como posso utilizar nomes de operadores do PHP em um método (controlador) ?

Exemplo:

```
public function new() {
   //Código aqui
}
```

Repare que usei o nome `new` o mesmo usado para instanciar um objeto.

Como ignorar esse nome em um método?

Comment: Sim é possível isso! desde que seja a versão 7. [No PHP 7, o método de classe pode conter um nome de palavra-chave? Isso é bom ou ruim?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128751/91)

Comment: Nas versões anteriores não tem como fazer nenhuma gambiarra pelo menos ?

Comment: Tem alguns jeitos, veja [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6833077/1342547)

Comment: Valeu amigo rray.